# MongoDb queries and system.linq

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, database, nosql

When i use System.linq to query objects in a MongoCollection:

```
var result = collection.Find(query).Where(x => x.something == something);
```

is this a query done on the database or on the collection in memory?

for instance "SetSkip" creates the query in MongoDb but "Skip" does it in memory.

If ".Where" is done in memory is there a way not to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `.Where` query is done in memory via `IEnumerable.Where` because it's performed on the result of the `Find` call that establishes the MongoDB query to perform.

To incorporate the `.Where` query into the `Find`, you can create a new query that ANDs the two queries together:

```
query = Query.And(query, Query<YourType>.EQ(x => x.something, something));
var result = collection.Find(query);
```